# Use config.json file's parameters in app

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

We are using google map api and we have a key. We have codede this key in one of our module file. We want to use this key in config.json file so that it should be secure and when we push our changes to git, it should not be available as we dont push our config.json file on git. I don't have any idea about this.

mobile-content.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'GOOGLE-API KEY',
      libraries: ['places']
    }),
```

hip-config.json

```
googleMapsApiKey: "GOOGLE-API KEY" <--- want to use here ONLY
```

I want to use this key in hip-config.json file only and want to remove it from mobile-content.module.ts file.

Is there any way to impliment such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import `hip-config.json` into your module file

`import config from "../config/hip-config.json";`

Replace the hard-coded key in the module

```

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'config.GOOGLE-API KEY',
      libraries: ['places']
    }),
```

```

Make sure that `hip-config.json` has been added to `.gitignore` so it doesn't accidentally get pushed.