# Ignore file on TFS

Tags: angular, tfs

This is related to my last question regarding json file. ([Use config.json file's parameters in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798523/use-config-json-files-parameters-in-app/50799430#50799430)). Everything works perfectly fine but when i push my code on TFS, there is no file mentioned on TFS like hip-config.json. Somehow, i want TFS should ignore that import command anyhow.Below is the error i got when build got failed.

I have added hip-congif.json file like below

```
import * as data from '../../hip-config.json';
```

Error

```
Error: Can't resolve '../../hip-config.json' in 'C:\agent_tfship\_work\1\s\app\mobile-content'
```

is there anyway in typescript to ignore file or something like that? I tried try..catch but i did not work. Tried to added existSync but this also did not work.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate empty file (if it does not exist) before executing angular build.

Comment: Sorry to say but i did not understand..can you please explain me?

Comment: You can use node package like `node-touch` and call `nodetouch  ./../hip-config.json` to create missing file right before executing `ng build`